# Very very slow to load with spinning circle on Windows - Explorer & Safari

Tags: video.js

I hope you can please help. I'm using the normal set up of video.js but it just takes a really long time to load up in Explorer 9/10 and in Safari on Windows.

Firefox in Windows plays the video immediately. And every browser on Linux and Mac loads it up straight away too.

But on Windows in Explorer and Safari I press play and get a spinning circle for about 2 minutes before the video starts. Can anyone please help?